# Is there a function in R to effectively transform the format of raw data file to the desired format?

Tags: r, transformation

i have a test dataset of vehicle probe data. (Please see below).

```
Vehicle ID,Trip ID,Link ID,GenTime
7351,95263521,100,20200108141411
7351,95263521,101,20200108141421
7351,95263521,102,20200108141431
7351,95263521,110,20200108141441
7363,95263553,123,20200108141403
7363,95263553,125,20200108141413
7363,95263553,157,20200108141423
7363,95263553,168,20200108141433
7363,95270158,121,20200108160458
7363,95270158,324,20200108160508
7363,95270158,568,20200108160518
7351,95270151,325,20200108160441
7351,95270151,628,20200108160451
7351,95270151,576,20200108160501
7351,95270151,231,20200108160511
7363,95270158,432,20200108160738
7363,95270158,231,20200108160748
7363,95270158,981,20200108160758
7351,95270151,954,20200108160721
7351,95270151,950,20200108160731
7351,95270151,958,20200108160741
7351,95270151,957,20200108160751
```

and I would like to transform them to the following format:

```
Vehicle ID, Trip ID, Link ID (From), GenTime (From), Link ID (To), GenTime (To)
7351,95263521,100,20200108141411,101,20200108141421
7351,95263521,101,20200108141421,102,20200108141431
7351,95263521,102,20200108141431,110,20200108141441
...
```

Qn 1: Is there an efficient way to do this in R?

Qn 2: Potentially, i may be able to receive data for a million vehicles and that may generate up to billions of rows of dataset everyday. Will R be capable to handle data of that volume?

Comment: What's your logic for going from the first version to the second? The code you've tried, even if it didn't work, might help make that clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `dplyr`, we can `group_by` `Vehicle.ID` and `Trip.ID` and use `lead`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Vehicle.ID, Trip.ID) %>%
  mutate(Link.ID_from = Link.ID, Link.ID_to = lead(Link.ID), 
         GenTime_from = GenTime, GenTime_to = lead(GenTime)) %>%
  select(-GenTime, -Link.ID)
```

---

The same can be done in `data.table` which might be faster for larger datasets

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, c('Link.ID_from', 'Link.ID_to','GenTime_from', 'GenTime_to') := 
        list(Link.ID, shift(Link.ID, type = "lead"),
        GenTime, shift(GenTime, type = "lead")), .(Vehicle.ID, Trip.ID)][,-c(3, 4)]
```